# Чтение файла .adm

Tags: c#, winforms, файлы

Есть задача - программа проверки правописания. В качестве словаря должен быть использован файл типа .adm (`Additional Dictionary`). Но я не знаю как хранятся данные в файле для их чтения. К сожалению гугл не смог помочь мне в этом вопросе. Пишу на C# `WinForm`. `WPF` и сторонние библиотеки не используются.

Comment: У вас имеется этот файл `.adm` или нужно разработать самостоятельно его формат?

Comment: @Alexander Petrov файл уже имеется.

http://www.addictivesoftware.com/addict3/dicts-extern.htm